# How to create a duplicated inputs more times?

Tags: javascript

I want to make this js working multiple times in the same page, it's works only with the first block

```
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var controlForm = $('.controls form:first'),
          currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:first'),
          newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);
      newEntry.find('.repeat').val('');
      controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .btn-add')
          .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
          .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
          .html('<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="css-i6dzq1"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><line x1="8" y1="12" x2="16" y2="12"></line></svg>'); 
  }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function (e) {
      $(this).parents('.entry:first').remove();
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
  });
```